# Graph Theory - Concept checking questions.

Tags: graph-theory

> Q. Suppose $G=(V,E)$ is a simple undirected graph with no self-loop; moreover, the graph $G$ has $n=|V| ≥ 1$ vertices, $m=|E|$ edges, $k$ connected components, $p$ odd cycles, $q$ even cycles and chromatic number $X$.
>
> Determine if the following is true.
>
> 1. if $p+q = 0$, then $m ≤ n-1$
> 2. if $p+q = 0$, then the graph is planar
> 3. if $p=3$, then $X=2$
> 4. if the graph is planar, then $X≥k$
> 5. if $X=n$, then $m=n(n−1)/2$

Attempt:

1. true
2. false
3. false
4. false
5. true

[image: Example or counter-example for the above choices]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1. True is correct. A proof will be along the lines that if there is no cycle, $G$ is a forest which are made up of trees. (Note $m=n-1$ for trees)

Q2. Answer should be true. A planar graph means a planar drawing is possible. Even though you have shown a non-planar drawing, the same graph (up to isomorphism) can be redrawn to be planar. Again why it is true comes from the fact that $G$ is a forest.

Q3. False is correct. (In fact, as long $p \geq 1$, the graph is not bipartite and cannot be colored with just 2 colors.)

Q4. False is correct. (The 4 color theorem for planar graphs will be an interesting extension to read up on if you haven't already encountered it.)

Q5. True is correct. To generalize your reasoning, if $X=n$, then $G$ must be a complete graph and the result follows.

Comment: What are that forest and trees you mentioned  in Q1 and Q2?

Comment: Sorry for the jargon. Trees are connected graphs (every vertex can reach another) that DO NOT contain any cycles. Forests are graphs that DO NOT contain any cycles (need not be connected.) The funny names come from the fact that forests are made up of trees. (Try to draw a forest that is not connected and spot the different trees inside!)

Comment: Got it! Thanks!